# How can I get a z depth pass in CoD 4 via console?

Tags: mods, call-of-duty-4-modern-warfare

I want to make a Call of Duty: Modern Warfare fragmovie and to make it look cool, I have to render several passes from my demos. To get some cool effects in the post, I would like to render a depth map from my demos.

My question is, does anyone know how to achieve that?

So far I used this console command:

```
r_floatZDebug 1
```

And this is the visual feedback I get from the renderer:

[image: Renderer feedback]

Even though this one is coloured, this is actually something I could work with. But as you can see, its not Fullscreen. Does anybody know how to force it? Or any other command than can get me what I want?